# Div stretch out into the corner part of the screen

Tags: html, css, stretch

so here's the situation.

I want my specific div to be stretch out to the right of the screen even though the user uses zoom in/out on their browser.

You'll see my example here http://jsfiddle.net/4LD7h/

So this is what it looks like when you zoom out that page.

http://i48.tinypic.com/14kjo1k.png

This is what I want to appear

http://i48.tinypic.com/zwgwwj.png

I don't want any horizontal scroll bars as possible.

Thank you. :)

Comment: do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/4LD7h/2/

Answer (score 0):

In 
**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:850px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

replace with

```
#container {
    text-align:left;
}
```

and

```
#center {
    background:#aa1616;
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

replace with

```
 #center {
        background:#aa1616;
        width:100%;
        height:500px;

    }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4LD7h/6/

Comment: Dude, remove the `<!doctype>` and `HTML` parts when writing fiddles, only use the stuff inside `body`!

Comment: Sorry, this is close but not what I need. I need it to be centered.